# aligning equalities = one below the other

Tags: equations, align

I have the following source of math text in LaTeX and I would like to ALIGN
all the equalities (=) to be one exactly below the other.
How shall I do that? See the last 2 lines of this question.
Can someone rewrite this chain of equalities into ALIGN enviroment?
I got stuck with it.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

It is clearer if you define $q_i = p_i \cdot f_i \cdot \overline{f}_i$

This is how it should be.

Then

$p \cdot f = p \cdot b_i \cdot f_i \qquad \text{(since } f = b_i \cdot f_i)$

$= d^*_i \cdot p_i \cdot f_i \qquad\text{(by naturality)}$

$= d^*_i \cdot p_i \cdot f_i \cdot \overline{f}_i \cdot f_i$ = \qquad (as $\overline{f}_i \cdot f_i = 1$)

$= d^*_i \cdot q_i \cdot f_i  \qquad \text{(by the definition of} q_i)$

$= q \cdot b_i \cdot f_i  \qquad \text{(by naturality)}$

$= q \cdot f  \text{(by naturality)}$

Hope that helps.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `align` environment from `amsmath` package

Comment: How do I begin and end the align enviroment? "\begin{align}" has failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

**Text left aligned**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 &\text{It is clearer if you define} &q_i &= p_i \cdot f_i \cdot \overline{f}_i\\
&\text{This is how it should be} & p \cdot f &= p \cdot b_i \cdot f_i\\
&\text{then} &&= d^*_i \cdot p_i \cdot f_i \qquad \text{(by neutrality)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Text right aligned**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \text{It is clearer if you define}& &q_i &= p_i \cdot f_i \cdot \overline{f}_i\\
\text{This is how it should be}& & p \cdot f &= p \cdot b_i \cdot f_i\\
\text{then} &&&= d^*_i \cdot p_i \cdot f_i \qquad \text{(by neutrality)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WHat is wrong with this: \begin{align}
$p \cdot f &= p \cdot b_i \cdot f_i \text{(since)} f = b_i \cdot f_i$\\

$&= d^*_i \cdot p_i \cdot f_i \text{(by naturality)}$\\

Comment: @user2925716 remove  all the $

Comment: Align already starts display math mode.  $ is for inline math.

Comment: I've managed myself to align that text. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user2925716 you're welcome!

Comment: Please, how do I align say "then" in the third line to the right? OR ALL 3 sentences there to the right?

Comment: @user2925716 answer updated